# Sorting a text file by cumulative total of one column from grouped values in another column using standard library only?

Tags: python, sorting, sum, cumulative-sum, accumulate

I have a file with rows like this

```
id, car_type, cost
1, benz, 60000
2, benz, 55000
3, bmw, 30000
4, benz, 25000
5, bmw, 26000
6, ford, 5000
```

I want to sort this file by total cost of each `car_type`. The total cost, for example, for '`benz`' would be `60000 + 55000 + 25000 = 14000`

so the final output should be

```
benz, 140000
bmw, 56000
ford, 5000
```

So far, this is what i have:

```
file = "small_sample.txt"


f=open(file,"r")
lines=f.readlines()[1:]
car_and_cost ={}
for x in lines:
    cost = x.split(',')[4].rstrip('\n')
    car_and_cost.update({x.split(',')[3]:float(cost)})
f.close()
print(car_and_cost)

new_dic = {}
for key,lis in car_and_cost.items():
    new_dic[key] = sum(lis)
print(new_dic)
```

I am pretty much stuck. First, the dictionary that i am generating from this is has incorrect totals and also i simply don't know how to sort a dictionary by value

Comment: Count the number of unique `car_type`s and then create a dictionary of that count, assigning the sum of values or each in the file. Ta-daah!

Comment: you may accept an answer that helped you solving the problem! Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one approach using `csv` and `collections` modules

**Ex:**

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict, OrderedDict

result = defaultdict(int)

with open(filename) as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    for row in reader:                    #Iterate Each row
        result[row[" car_type"]] += int(row[" cost"])   #Add costs

print(OrderedDict(sorted(result.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)))
```

**Output:**

```
OrderedDict([(' benz', 140000), (' bmw', 56000), (' ford', 5000)])
```

Comment: This looks promising. It doesn't seem to sort though. I'd like to have the key with highest total come first. So descending sort. Also, how well does this scale? For say maybe 1 million rows.

Comment: `print(OrderedDict(sorted(result.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)))`

Answer (score 1):

Using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(logFile)

result = df.groupby(' car_type').sum()
print(result)
```

OUTPUT:

```
           id    cost
 car_type            
 benz       7  140000
 bmw        8   56000
 ford       6    5000
```

EDIT:

```
logFile = "tem.csv"
array = []
import csv

with open("tem.csv", "r+") as fin:
    for row in csv.reader(fin):
        array.append(row[1:])

dd = {k: 0 for k in dict(array).keys()}
for x in array: dd[x[0]] += int(x[1])
print(dd)
```

OUTPUT:

```
{' benz': 140000, ' bmw': 56000, ' ford': 5000}
```

OR if you want them in a list:

```
print([[k,v] for k,v in  dd.items()])
```

OUTPUT:

```
[[' benz', 140000], [' bmw', 56000], [' ford', 5000]]
```

Comment: Using standard library only

Comment: @Tendi Edited my answer.

Comment: is this memory efficient? Doesn't csv need to load the whole file into memory? What happens if say the file is 5GB? And also the final sort by highest cumulative cost

Comment: @Tendi no, it is only a pointer. It won't load the whole file into the memory.